# Acache: wsgi and alias incompatibility

Tags: apache, mod-wsgi, mod-alias

I am trying to setup Apache so that:

- if the user goes to `/temp` then the file `/home/temp/public_html/index.html` is served
- if the user goes to `/temp/app` then my mod-wsgi `/home/temp/app/start.wsgi` is executed

I currently have this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    WSGIDaemonProcess temp user=temp group=temp home=/home/temp/app
    WSGIScriptAlias /temp/app /home/temp/app/start.wsgi
    Alias /temp /home/temp/public_html

    <Directory /home/temp/app>
        WSGIProcessGroup temp
        WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost *:80>
```

But oddly enough `Alias` seems to take predence over `WSGIScriptAlias` and `/temp/app` does not work...

Comment: For a start, read http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/configuration-guidelines.html Because of precedence order that Apache enforces you can't use ``WSGIScriptAlias`` in the particular scenario you want, but will need to use ``Alias`` and ``AddHandler`` for the WSGI application.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton Thanks :) Still no cigar... Even after defining `Alias` after `WSGIScriptAlias`, my `/temp/app` does not work. I have updated my post...

Comment: By the way, I have been able to make it work using `AddHandler`. The problem is that it seems I will need to use `Rewrite` to get rid of the .wsgi extensions. I would prefer to just use `WSGIScriptAlias`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got closer in your own answer, but not quite. Use something like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    WSGIDaemonProcess temp user=temp group=temp home=/home/temp/app
    Alias /temp/app /home/temp/app/start.wsgi
    Alias /temp /home/temp/public_html

    <Directory /home/temp/app>
        WSGIProcessGroup temp
        WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
        Require all granted

        Options ExecCGI
        AddHandler wsgi-script .wsgi
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: This works without all the hacks to hide the extension since the Alias takes care of that. Simple and brilliant! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Not particularly pretty, but I have (at least for the time being) solved it this way:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  WSGIDaemonProcess temp user=temp group=temp home=/home/temp/app
  <Directory /home/temp/app>
    WSGIProcessGroup temp
    WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}

    Options ExecCGI MultiViews
    MultiviewsMatch Handlers
    AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
    AddHandler wsgi-script .wsgi

    Require all granted
  </Directory>

  Alias /temp /home/temp/app
</VirtualHost>
```

Instead of using `WSGIScriptAlias`, I define it to automatically run `.wsgi` files. The `MultiViews` option matches `file` to `file.wsgi`.

Furthermore, to hide the extension from my own script, in each `.wsgi` I have to redefine the script filename:

```
from server_public import app as _application  # my flask app
# get rid of the .wsgi extension
def application(environ, start_response):
    if environ['SCRIPT_NAME'].endswith('.wsgi'):
        environ['SCRIPT_NAME'] = environ['SCRIPT_NAME'][:-5]
    return _application(environ, start_response)
```

I also had to move my `public_html/index.html` to `app/index.html`.

---

I would prefer a simpler solutions where I served `index.html` for `/temp`, and a script alias for `/temp/app`... But not sure that is possible...